# selected="selected" field in opencart 2.1

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm using one module AJAX `d_quickcheckout` for faster checkout page on `opencart 2.1` (not the default one). The problem is with one field on `payment address` section not to be selected by `default`, this is `region/state` field. At the moment the field has the region/state where the store is located.

Even if I remove the field, this `region/state` doesn't show at the checkout page but is shown on `invoice`!

I want this field to be like `--Select State--` or with default `value="0"` and `$text_none`

These are the two code blocks that I think I must change:

HTML

```
<select name="payment_address[address_id]" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 15px;" data-refresh="3">
          <?php foreach ($addresses as $address) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $address['address_id']; ?>" <?php echo ($address['address_id'] == $payment_address['address_id']) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>> 
                <?php echo $address['firstname']; ?> 
                <?php echo $address['lastname']; ?>, 
                <?php echo $address['address_1']; ?>, 
                <?php echo $address['city']; ?>, 
                <?php echo $address['zone']; ?>, 
                <?php echo $address['country']; ?> 
              </option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
```

AJAX:

```
function refreshPaymentAddessZone(value) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=module/quickcheckout/country&country_id=' + value,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        complete: function() {

        },      
        success: function(json) {

            if (json['postcode_required'] == '1') {
                $('#payment-postcode-required').show();
            } else {
                $('#payment-postcode-required').hide();
            }

            html = '<option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>';

            if (json['zone'] != '') {

                for (i = 0; i < json['zone'].length; i++) {
                    html += '<option value="' + json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] + '"';
                    if (json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] == '<?php echo $payment_address['fields']['zone_id']['value']; ?>') {
                        html += ' selected="selected"';
                    }

                    html += '>' + json['zone'][i]['name'] + '</option>';
                }
            } else {
                html += '<option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_none; ?></option>';
            }

            $('#payment_address_wrap select[name=\'payment_address[zone_id]\']').html(html);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can comment the $.ajax call and the dropdown will be empty all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code block, instead of your currect select:

```
<select name="payment_address[address_id]" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 15px;" data-refresh="3">
    <option value="0">-- Select State --</option>
      <?php foreach ($addresses as $address) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $address['address_id']; ?>"> 
            <?php echo $address['firstname']; ?> 
            <?php echo $address['lastname']; ?>, 
            <?php echo $address['address_1']; ?>, 
            <?php echo $address['city']; ?>, 
            <?php echo $address['zone']; ?>, 
            <?php echo $address['country']; ?> 
          </option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

If this isn't sufficient, remove the AJAX-call as well.